# How to allow unique Laravel Facade instances when using Builder pattern?

Tags: php, laravel, facade

Im using the Builder pattern but get data mixup between calls. I want a fresh instance on each static call to my facade. Example:

#### Underlying class

```
<?php

namespace Me\Package;

class PHPFile
{
    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        return isset($this->$key) ? $this->key : 'NO_SUCH_KEY';
    }

    public function sum()
    {
        // example of an "ending" method
    }
}
```

#### The facade

```
<?php

namespace Me\Package\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class PHPFile extends Facade {
   protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'PHPFile'; }
}
```

#### Serviceprovider

```
use Me\Package\PHPFile;

public function register()
{
    App::bind('PHPFile',function() {
        return new PHPFile;
    });
}
```

#### Test

```
print PHPFile::set('first', 10)->set('second', 20)->sum();
// 30
print PHPFile::get('first');
// 10 !!!
```

Since facades keep the same instance the second test row will print `10`. I want 'NO_SUCH_KEY' here - a new instance after each static call. How can I do that? I tried making the facade return a minimal "factory", simply a constructor returning a new `PHPFile` instance but did not succeed that way. I also read I should call a `new static` in the "ending"-methods (sum/get) but not sure how to do that and keep the accumulated data.

Comment: Why not make this a part of the `PHPFile` logic (making new instances and so on) ...? It seems that it should have that responsability

Comment: I want to enable a static chainable API using the Builder pattern

Comment: I don't think you can, and in addition I don't think you should. Please find a different solution to your problem. The main purpose of facades is to wrap around singletons. This being said if you just want to reset the facade you can just do `PHPFile::swap(app()->make('PHPFile'))`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just updated the question to clarify the purpose. This is very similar to Laravels QueryBuilder so there really should be some way to do it though? I never had queries collide?

Comment: The `DB` facade is a facade of the [DatabaseManager](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0e8f66281291b002cb1e637a07c11f06b0b1a844/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php) and not the query builder. The database manager singleton is responsible for returning a query builder instance. This means there's  no conflict between queries because that's not the facade singleton

Answer (score 1):

#### Add a factory

This factory will intercept any call with magic `__call` method, then dispatch it to a fresh PHPFile (My Builder class)

```
<?php

namespace Me\Package\Factories;

use Me\Package\PHPFile;

class PHPFileFactory
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return (new PHPFile)->$method(...$args);
    }    
}
```

#### Bind the *factory* in the serviceprovider

```
App::bind('PHPFile',function() {
    return new PHPFileFactory;
});
```

Thanks to @apokryfos who pointed out I needed to return something else - not the Builder itself but another class.